# Hash Table v/s STL map in C++

Tags: c++, hashtable, hashmap

I am trying to learn C++ maps. Was just wondering about the implementation of STL map. I read it employs Binary search tree.

1. Is there a implementation of hash table in STL?
2. How exactly do STL map stores Key Value pairs?

Answer (score 13):

Typical STL  implementations are based on Red-Black trees.  C++ TR1 provides std::tr1::unordered_map which uses a hash table implementation.  Boost also provides an unordered_map hash table implementation.

C++11 now has [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Comment: And MSVC has `stdext::hash_map`, gcc has `__gnucxx::hash_map`, and of course in C++0x the TR1 `unordered_map` will move to the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

1. Some libraries implement `stdext::hash_map` which has almost the same interface as `std::map` but uses a hash table instead of a binary tree.
2. The binary tree nodes are arranged in the tree according the key, and each key has a value attached, either in whole in the same node, or as a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The key-value pairs are stored in an `std::pair`.  Its a templated struct; an element called `first` stores the key, and an element called `second` stores the value.  [Some info.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/)