# Why C++ STL does not provide hashtable and union data structures?

Tags: c++, stl

At various places, I've read that STL does not provide hashtable and union data structures. How could these be implemented using other existing STL data structures?

Comment: You might be interested in `hashmap` implementation in C++ here: http://epsilon-delta.net/code/hashmap.html

Comment: What do you mean by a union structure - different from a regular `union`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460387/hash-table-v-s-stl-map-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the [std::tr1::unordered_map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_map_%28C%2B%2B%29) for your hash map.  std::map is ordered, so it's not really as efficient as hash.  Not sure what you mean by a union data structure, but you can have unioned structs in C++

**EDIT:** Additionally there are many other implementations of hash maps that some have done.  Boost has an [unordered map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/unordered.html), Prasoon mentioned one in the question comments, and Google has [sparsehash](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/).

Answer (score 1):

Try std::map for your hash table needs...

Comment: `std::map` is actually a binary tree, not a hashtable. As SB says, `unordered_map` is a hashtable. (Technically, the standard doesn't specify how the map is to be implemented, but the constraints specified by the standard imply a binary tree - and that's certainly the most common implementation)

Comment: That's tree-based and has different performance characteristics to a hash table (lookup is logarithmic time for a tree, versus constant time for a hash table). C++0x introduces `unordered_map` based on hash tables. Some implementations may provide `hash_map`, which was part of the original STL but wasn't included in the Standard Library.

Comment: Actually, `std::map` requirements does not imply a binary tree (and certainly not a red-black tree or an AVL tree even though those are the most common implementations). A Skip List would work.